# Suddenly lost all cronjobs

Tags: debian, cron

All of a sudden my `cron` jobs don't work any more.
When I type

```
crontab -e
```

I am presented an empty file in the editor

```
/tmp/crontab.3fMYGi/crontab
```

And by empty I mean that not even this standard `cron` job info is there any more.

Is there a way to recover my `cron` jobs?

Comment: You probably overwrote your crontab file, or deleted with `crontab -r`. Restoring from backup is probably the only option unless you put your `/etc` directory under revision control.

Comment: @Anthon user crontabs are in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`, so `/etc` under revision control won't help, unfortunately.

Comment: Use a version control system (rcs for /etc) to version these files.  And if you are deploying a system, keeping the relevant modifications to crontab versioned is imperative.

Comment: You might consider automating "crontab -l" to capture your current crontab nightly/weekly...

Comment: @derobert You are absolutely right. And I realise I have failed to put those files under revision control on my system for a long time, fortunately I also have backups.

Comment: @Anthon I'd suggest system cron jobs should go in /etc/cron.d not in a random user crontab. Even if that random user is root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Anthon said in comments, you most likely have lost your crontab entries. On the off chance you haven't, they would be located here in this directory: `/var/spool/cron/` in a file named after your username.

If they aren't there either then they're lost and you'll have to recreate them or get them from backups.

You might also get lucky and find the remnant of the tmp file used to edit them when you run the command `crontab -e`. These files would be in `/tmp/crontab.*`.

Comment: aren't crontab.* files removed like... after everything is done?

Comment: @Braiam - usually but they wouldn't have been if someone did a control+Z and/or killed the process.

Comment: thanks! there actually is a file in /var/spool/cron/ butit contains only a warning about not editing it.

Comment: @clamp - yeah that's what I was afraid of. In the future if you notice this problem you can quickly copy that file before doing any saves via `crontab -e`. It's a small window but is possible.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative for cases where the original crontab is not recoverable, the commands executed by cron are often logged. So one could conceivably recover a large percentage of the actual commands that have been executed via cron as far back in time as the logs exist.

```
# grep 'cron\.\*' /etc/syslog.conf
cron.*                          /var/log/cron

# grep CMD /var/log/cron*
/var/log/cron:Oct  4 04:10:01 azdb01 crond[24774]: (root) CMD (...)
```

The times and frequency settings of each command would of course take some detailed investigation of these logs to recreate.

Comment: Awesome. You saved {almost} :) my life.